# Linux device driver for multiple busses

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, i2c

I am trying to get I2C bus driver working for my embedded product.

The driver is currently working fine for bus 0 but it is not working for bus 1.

I see that there is a file named i2c-product.c (I have replaced the name of the chip i2c controller with 'product') and I believe that is the driver for the controller.

It has a function `product_i2c_probe(struct platform_device *pd)`.  I see that this is a callback assigned in the platform_driver structure to .probe member.  I guess kernel calls into it to setup the driver. Makes sense.

Inside the `product_i2c_probe(struct platform_device *pd)` function there are following lines to setup the adapter:

```
drv_data->adapter.dev.parent = &pd->dev;
drv_data->adapter.algo = &product_i2c_algo;
drv_data->adapter.owner = THIS_MODULE;
drv_data->adapter.class = I2C_CLASS_HWMON | I2C_CLASS_SPD;
drv_data->adapter.timeout = msecs_to_jiffies(pdata->timeout);
drv_data->adapter.nr = pd->id;
```

From exploring the code in i2c-core.c and i2c-dev.c, it appears like nr member of the adapter needs to contain the bus id, because that is what gets the minor from the device node.  Note I have also created the node using mknod command for both buses.  So I have a device /dev/i2c-0 and /dev/i2c-1.

Later in the `product_i2c_probe(struct platform_device *pd)` function, it adds the adapter to the device using `i2c_add_numbered_adapter(&drv_data->adapter)`.

At the end of the file, I see it registers the device:

```
static int __init
product_i2c_init(void)
{
    return platform_driver_register(&product_i2c_driver);
}
```

And finally

```
module_init(product_i2c_init);
```

So my question is, who calls into the probe() function and passes the platform_device *pd.  Clearly this object has the pd->id value that becomes the bus id for the adapter in the line:

```
drv_data->adapter.nr = pd->id;
```

Is there a configuration file somewhere?  I searched all over but could not find it including the menuconfig.

Any help will be appreciated.  As you can probably guess, I am a newbie to device drivers.  Am I on the right track, or totally off?

Thanks.

Comment: You are on the right track.  The resources and their associated names in the board file defined for your project will trigger the probe().  See this file (http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/mach-msm/board-trout-gpio.c?a=arm) and the other files in its directory as an example.

Comment: *"Is there a configuration file somewhere?"* -- What version of the Linux kernel are you using?  Is there a **Device Tree**?  What arch, SoC and board is this for?